# Multi file PHP code in drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I have an application separated into 4 files of PHP.
the main PHP code and win/lose/exit pages of the application.

when I implement the code into a node, on drupal, the main PHP file presented with no problem at all.
while I click on exit, linked to other node containing the exit.php code, the layout of the page get messed up.

If you need the code just let me know, it seems more of problem with linking between drupal nodes containing PHP code.

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have written the php code almost as a standalone application and you are then including this in the drupal node by writing PHP. Is this the case?

If it is why did you not chose to write it as a module?

Comment: yep, you don't need to hardcode, you can create a module and implement hooks to create node(s) or so.